# Repeated and grouped values in Mysql

Tags: mysql, count

How to calculate how many times the value 0 is repeated in a table only if that value is constant by 3 or more times (constant being repeated in next row)

in this case it would be 2 occasions that the value 0 is repeated more than 3 times.

```
+-----------+-------+---------------------+
| idDataGps | speed | eventDate           |
+-----------+-------+---------------------+
|    143483 |    56 | 2017-05-18 08:42:05 |
|    143484 |     0 | 2017-05-18 08:42:11 |
|    143485 |     0 | 2017-05-18 08:42:20 |
|    143486 |     0 | 2017-05-18 08:42:35 |
|    143487 |    43 | 2017-05-18 08:42:40 |
|    143488 |    44 | 2017-05-18 08:42:50 |
|    143489 |    48 | 2017-05-18 08:43:05 |
|    143490 |    24 | 2017-05-18 08:43:14 |
|    143491 |    34 | 2017-05-18 08:43:16 |
|    143492 |     9 | 2017-05-18 08:43:20 |
|    143493 |    14 | 2017-05-18 08:43:36 |
|    143494 |     0 | 2017-05-18 08:44:06 |
|    143495 |     0 | 2017-05-18 08:44:21 |
|    143496 |     0 | 2017-05-18 08:46:06 |
|    143497 |     0 | 2017-05-18 08:48:36 |
|    143498 |     0 | 2017-05-18 08:48:42 |
+-----------+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: MySQL rows aren't ordered. Do you have another column that provides an order, like a datetime or an ID?

Comment: yes sorry, i have consecutive ids and datetime timestamp, edit in my question with actual database query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use user-defined variables to keep state from one row to the next. Use one variable `@zerocount` to count consecutive zero speeds; it gets reset back to 0 whenever `speed != 0`, and increments whenever `speed = 0`. Another variable `@counter` gets incremented whenever a non-zero value is encountered, so all the consecutive zeroes will be in the same `@counter` group.

Then to find out how long the run of zeroes is, we use `MAX(zerocount)` grouped by `counter`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT counter, MAX(zerocount) AS maxcount
    FROM (
        SELECT speed, IF(speed = 0, @zerocount := @zerocount+1, @zerocount := 0) as zerocount,
            IF(speed != 0, @counter := @counter + 1, @counter) AS counter
        FROM (SELECT speed FROM yourTable ORDER BY eventDate) AS t
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @counter := 0, @zerocount := 0) AS var
    ) AS x
    GROUP BY counter
) AS y
WHERE maxcount >= 3
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71eead/5)

Comment: Just amazing! great approach with variables, i was stuck on this one

Comment: Now, if i want to know the total time spent on speed = 0, can i make it on the same query or should i make a new one with similar logic?

This 2 times spent on 0 speed how much time they sum?

Comment: You can use another variable to add up the time differences between `eventDate` on consecutive lines of 0.