# How to generate sequence numbers based on time intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, session, sequence

I have the following data:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| IDUSER  | ACCESS_TIME            | IPLOG    | SESSIONX    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|1        |  2018-02-05 04:01:17   |  1.2.3.4 |             |
|1        |  2018-02-05 04:05:00   |  1.2.3.4 |             |
|1        |  2018-02-05 04:40:00   |  1.2.3.4 |             |
|1        |  2018-02-05 07:00:14   |  1.2.3.4 |             |
|1        |  2018-02-05 07:50:14   |  1.2.3.5 |             |
|2        |  2018-02-05 08:20:20   |  1.2.3.5 |             |
|2        |  2018-02-05 08:35:00   |  1.2.3.5 |             |
|2        |  2018-02-05 08:45:20   |  1.2.3.6 |             |
|2        |  2018-02-05 09:35:00   |  1.2.3.6 |             |
```

the goal is to know how many times (SESSIONX)
user logs based on IDUSER, ACCESS_TIME, IPLOG.
with the following rules:

- new session increases (+1) if its access every interval over 30 minutes (> 30 minutes) but with the same iplog
- if user access with iplog is different (new), even under 30 minutes (<30 minutes)
  from the previous time then counted a new session (+1).

How to make the query of the session time sequence with the above rule? , so the output as below

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| IDUSER  | ACCESS_TIME            | IPLOG    | SESSIONX    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|1        |  2018-02-05 04:01:17   |  1.2.3.4 | 1            |
|1        |  2018-02-05 04:05:00   |  1.2.3.4 | 1            |
|1        |  2018-02-05 04:40:00   |  1.2.3.4 | 2            |
|1        |  2018-02-05 07:00:14   |  1.2.3.4 | 3            |
|1        |  2018-02-05 07:50:14   |  1.2.3.5 | 4            |
|2        |  2018-02-05 08:20:20   |  1.2.3.5 | 1            |
|2        |  2018-02-05 08:35:00   |  1.2.3.5 | 1            |
|2        |  2018-02-05 08:45:20   |  1.2.3.6 | 2            |
|2        |  2018-02-05 09:35:00   |  1.2.3.6 | 3            |
```

Comment: Use user-defined variables. One variable holds the last `IDUSER`, another holds the last `ACCESS_TIME`, another holds the last `IPLOG`, and the last one holds `SESSIONX`. You increment or reset `SESSIONX` depending on how the columns in the current row compare to the saved variables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059853/repeated-and-grouped-values-in-mysql/44059965#44059965 for similar use of variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IDUSER,
       ACCESS_TIME,
       IPLOG,
       SESSIONX
FROM
(SELECT 
T.IDUSER,
T.ACCESS_TIME,
T.IPLOG,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,@date,T.ACCESS_TIME),
CASE WHEN @id != T.IDUSER THEN @num := 1 END,
CASE WHEN @iplog != T.IPLOG OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,@date,T.ACCESS_TIME) > 30 
THEN @num := @num + 1 
ELSE
@num
END AS SESSIONX,
@date := T.ACCESS_TIME AS VarDate,
@id := T.IDUSER AS VarIDUSER,
@iplog := T.IPLOG AS VarIPLOG
FROM
Table1 T,(SELECT @num := 1,@date := null,@id := null,@iplog := null) R)T1
```

**Output**

```
IDUSER  ACCESS_TIME         IPLOG     SESSIONX
1   2018-02-05T04:01:17Z    1.2.3.4   1
1   2018-02-05T04:05:00Z    1.2.3.4   1
1   2018-02-05T04:40:00Z    1.2.3.4   2
1   2018-02-05T07:00:14Z    1.2.3.4   3
1   2018-02-05T07:50:14Z    1.2.3.5   4
2   2018-02-05T08:20:20Z    1.2.3.5   1
2   2018-02-05T08:35:00Z    1.2.3.5   1
2   2018-02-05T08:45:20Z    1.2.3.6   2
2   2018-02-05T09:35:00Z    1.2.3.6   3
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44063e/42